# Mobile and Desktop Webpage Implementation

Tags: html, css, web, mobile, responsive

How can I go about creating a website with separate designs for both desktop and mobile browsers?

Comment: Your title and body appear to ask completely different questions.

Comment: I made a mistake with a word. Still sounds different for you?

Comment: No. The title asks how to *not* resize the website, whereas the body asks how to have separate desktop and mobile versions of a site.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking the latter.

Comment: i'm clear now. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options:

1. **Responsive web design** via [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

   From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive):

   > Responsive web apps use technologies like media queries and viewport to make sure that their UIs will fit any form factor: desktop, mobile, tablet, or whatever comes next.
2. **Separate mobile and desktop versions**, chosen via [user agent detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

   MDN has [some discussion of pros and cons of this approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Mobile/Separate_sites).